# bash: Assigning the first line of a variable to a variable

Tags: bash

I have a multiline variable, and I only want the first line in that variable.  The following script demonstrates the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRINGTEST="Onlygetthefirstline
butnotthesecond
orthethird"

echo "  Take the first line and send to standard output:"
echo ${STRINGTEST%%$'\n'*}
#   Output is as follows:
# Onlygetthefirstline

echo "  Set the value of the variable to the first line of the variable:"
STRINGTEST=${STRINGTEST%%$'\n'*}

echo "  Send the modified variable to standard output:"
echo $STRINGTEST
#   Output is as follows:
# Onlygetthefirstline butnotthesecond orthethird
```

Question:  Why does `${STRINGTEST%%$'\n'*}` return the first line when placed after an `echo` command, but replace newlines with spaces when placed after assignment?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. It works for me as expected.

Comment: Can't reproduce with any of 2.05b, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 either. Sounds like a user error like trying to run it with a shell that doesn't support `$'...'` instead of bash.

Comment: Your solution in the Question section seems to works for me as a correct answer

Comment: The `${STRINGTEST%%$'\n'*}` works on my system as intended, on assignment as well; my Bash version is 5.0.17.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe there is other way to archive what you want to do, but this works

```
#!/bin/bash

STRINGTEST="
Onlygetthefirstline
butnotthesecond
orthethird
"

STRINGTEST=(${STRINGTEST[@]})
echo "${STRINGTEST[0]}"
```

Comment: That assumes the lines in `$STRINGTEST` don't contain blanks or wildcards. Also note that empty lines (as in the first line in that variable) are ignored.

Comment: Also note that using `STRINGTEST=(${STRINGTEST[@]})` makes little sense and is equivalent to `STRINGTEST=($STRINGTEST)` since `STRINGTEST` was previously defined as a _scalar_ (not _array_) variable.

Comment: No!!!

It's funny you even quoted `${STRINGTEST[0]}`

Comment: @pihentagy could you explain why is funny?

Comment: @c4f4t0r yep. In the previous line you have just splitted the string to WORDs. Try changing the first line of stringtest to `hello world`.

The expression mentioned in the question itself (`${STRINGTEST%%$'\n'*}`) however seems to correctly solve the problem

Comment: @pihentagy if I use "hell world" in the first it will not work, that's clear :)

Answer (score 32):

might not be most efficient but one liner...

```
firstLine=`echo "${multiLineVariable}" | head -1`
```

Comment: I like it for clarity and brevity.

Comment: This ``firstLine=`echo "${test_var}" | sed -n 1p`` also works if you have a reason to use sed instead (e.g., it means you can simultaneously perform a replacement to the line: `echo "${test_var}" | sed -nE '1 s/# *(.*)/\1/p'`.

Answer (score 8):

That code works for me with all versions of bash I tried between 2.05b and 4.3. More likely you tried to run that script with a different shell that doesn't support the `$'...'` form of quoting.

That `$'...'` syntax is not standard `sh` syntax (yet) and only supported (as of 2015-05-22 and AFAIK) by `ksh93` (where it originated), `zsh`, `bash`, recent versions of `mksh` and the [`sh` or recent versions of FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/sh/sh.1?revision=221513&view=markup).

My bet would be that you tried to run that script with `sh` instead of `bash` and your `sh` is based on versions of `ash`, `pdksh`, `yash` or `ksh88` that don't support it yet.

If you want to make that code POSIX 2008 compatible, you'd need to write it:

```
STRINGTEST="Onlygetthefirstline
butnotthesecond
orthethird"

NL='
'
STRINGTEST=${STRINGTEST%%"$NL"*}
printf '%s\n' "$STRINGTEST"
```

Then, you can have it interpreted by any POSIX compliant shell like `bash` or any leaner/faster ones like your `sh`.

(and remember that leaving a variable unquoted in list context has a very special meaning in Bourne-like shells).

Comment: Or it could be an older version of bash. I could reproduce the behavior with 2.03.

Comment: @Gilles, the last supported OS that included bash-2.03 (released 16 years ago) was probably Solaris 8 which went EOL over 3 years ago. That hypothesis seems pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
STRINGTEST="Some Text 1
Some Text 2
Some Text 3"

readarray -t lines < <(echo "$STRINGTEST")
echo "${lines[0]}"
```

And it also works for blank lines:

```
STRINGTEST="
Some Text 1
Some Text 2
Some Text 3"

readarray -t lines < <(echo "$STRINGTEST")
echo "${lines[0]}"
```

Comment: If one bothers to fire up process substitution one could as well simply `read` once into a simple variable (instead of `readarray` plus indexing).

Answer (score 0):

With Bash built-in `read` and here-string:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

STRINGTEST="
Some Text 1
Some Text 2
Some Text 3"


IFS=$'\n' read -r STRINGTEST <<<"$STRINGTEST"
```

Using POSIX parameters expansion:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

STRINGTEST="
Some Text 1
Some Text 2
Some Text 3"

# Disables globing
set -f

# Field separator is newline only
IFS="
"

# No quotes, split lines as arguments because of IFS
set -- $STRINGTEST

# First argument is first line
STRINGTEST="$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have found this post with the same problem , but my solution was using the head commnand.

Like as an example:

```
vfail2ban=$(fail2ban-server --version |head -1)
root@vm:~# echo ${vfail2ban}
Fail2Ban v0.10.2
```